# jQuery - How do I submit the cloned forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

How can I submit all the cloned forms at the same time?

I made a script to clone my form, and I want to submit all the cloned forms. How can I do that?

HTML:

```
        <div id='forms'>
        <div class='cform'>

        <form id='form' method='POST'>   

            <input style='width: 80px;' class='hihi' type='submit' name='add_jo' value='Submit all' />

             <td><input class='txtedit' placeholder='Job name' type='text'  name='jo[]' maxlength='130' /></td>

    </form>

  </div>
 </div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.clone').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var tr = $('.cform:first');
    var newTr = tr.clone();
    newTr.find(":input").val(''); // find all input types (input, textarea etc), empty it.
    newTr.appendTo(tr.parent());
});
```

Comment: What's a lonely `td` doing inside a `form`? o.O

Comment: i was doing this stuff using a table, so i forgot to remove the <td> tags, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting a form is triggering request for new page load, thus you can't submit several forms simultaenously. Try to collect all forms' values in a hidden form to be submitted or use some AJAX to do the job without actually submitting form data.

Alternatively you could clone your form's content to extend the form itself.

```
<form action="..." method="post">
    <div class="cloneable">
        <input name="data[]" value="" />
    </div>
    <button id="extend">Clone</button>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Your JS might look like this:

```
 $("#extend").click( function() {
      $(".cloneable")
          .clone()
          .insertBefore( $("#extend") );
 } );
```